# select for update if not null with exception or return value

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, sql-update

I have two threads, both need to update the same row.
The row looks like:

- (id, firstName, lastName)
- (1, "xxxx", null)
- 1 is the primary key value

Update looks like:

```
Update table set lastName = "yyy" where id = 1 and lastName = null;
```

What I want is if one thread successfully updates the null lastName to new value, I want second thread to fail and throw some sort of exception back to the caller. I need a way to know during update that the column is not null anymore (which means it was updated by first thread)

Which update statement will solve my problem? (`select for update`, `coalesce` etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it security in default read committed isolation.

for exp :

```
SESSION A : 
digoal=# create table t_curr(id int, c1 text, c2 text);
CREATE TABLE
digoal=# insert into t_curr values (1,'t',null);
INSERT 0 1
digoal=# begin;
BEGIN
digoal=# update t_curr set c2='ttt' where id=1 and c2 is null;
UPDATE 1
SESSION B : 
digoal=# update t_curr set c2='ttwt' where id=1 and c2 is null;
SESSION A : 
digoal=# end;
COMMIT
SESSION B : 
UPDATE 0
digoal=# select * from t_curr ;
 id | c1 | c2  
----+----+-----
  1 | t  | ttt
(1 row)
```

but if you like to raise error when update zero rows, you shold use repeatable read isolation.
for exp :

```
SESSION A : 
digoal=# update t_curr set c2 = null;
UPDATE 1
digoal=# begin transaction isolation level repeatable READ ;
BEGIN
digoal=# update t_curr set c2='ttt' where id=1 and c2 is null;
UPDATE 1

SESSION B : 
digoal=# begin transaction isolation level repeatable READ ;
BEGIN
digoal=# update t_curr set c2='ttt' where id=1 and c2 is null;

SESSION A : 
digoal=# end;
COMMIT

SESSION B : 
ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update
```

or you shold use function to update , and raise error.
for exp :

```
SESSION a : 
digoal=# update t_curr set c2 = null;
UPDATE 1
digoal=# begin;
BEGIN
digoal=# do language plpgsql $$
declare
begin
  update t_curr set c2='ttt' where id=1 and c2 is null;
  if not found then
    raise 'update 0';
  end if;
end;
$$;
DO
SESSION B : 
digoal=# begin;
BEGIN
digoal=# do language plpgsql $$
declare
begin
  update t_curr set c2='ttt' where id=1 and c2 is null;
  if not found then
    raise 'update 0';
  end if;
end;
$$;
SESSION A : 
digoal=# end;
COMMIT
SESSION B : 
ERROR:  update 0
digoal=# end;
ROLLBACK
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query itself is fine, just wrap it in a serializable transaction:

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;`

In this isolation level you'll get an error in your application code that you may chose to handle, either by aborting or retrying the transaction.

More info:

- http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html

Answer (score 0):

#### Isolation level

This can be done with regular `UPDATE` commands - in the [*default* isolation level `READ COMMITTED`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/transaction-iso.html). All of this is safe for concurrent use.

You *could* use `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`. This would generate a serialization failure exception automatically. But that makes the whole transactions much more expensive. Use one of the following methods in default isolation level instead:

#### Faulty command

Your original command had two errors:

- *Values* are enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes: `'yyy'`.
- `something = NULL` is always `NULL`. Use `something IS NULL` instead. [Details in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparison.html)

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    lastname = 'yyy'
WHERE  tbl_id = 1
AND    lastname IS NULL;
```

#### [Command tag](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html#AEN82079)

It tells you how many rows were affected:

```
UPDATE count
```

Only the first `UPDATE` actually gets to update the row. All following attempts do nothing and return `UPDATE 0`.

#### [`RETURNING` clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html)

An `UPDATE` can return rows directly:

```
UPDATE tbl
...
RETURNING lastname; -- value from *new* row
```

Only the first `UPDATE` returns a value. All following return *no row*.

#### PL/pgSQL function raising exception

If you actually *need* an exception:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_upd(_tbl_id int, _lastname text)
 RETURNS void AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE tbl
   SET    lastname = $2
   WHERE  tbl_id = $1
   AND    lastname IS NULL;

   IF NOT FOUND
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'UPDATE found no row.';
   END IF;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```